# MySQL query inside python program returning unexpected 'b' inside the tuple fetched from the query execution

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm writing a DBMS and am validating user inputs ( for tables in the database ) using the lengths and data_types stored in the MySQL database's INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for the particular table they are entering data into. Im using Python 3.8.4 ( 64 bit ) with all the needed mysql connector modules installed etc and i have the mysql server running on a local host on the same machine.
After executing the following query = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''my_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'the_specific_table';"
with the following python code:

NOTE: the particular table im using in this query is set out like below

user_id    -    INT     -       PRIMARY KEY- NOT NULL

first_name    -   VARCHAR(45) -   NOT NULL

last_name    -    VARCHAR(45)  -  NOT NULL

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = host,
    user = user,
    passwd = password,
    database = db_name)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_HERE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_HERE';")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

The result i get from this query is  the following
-- >
[(b'int',), (b'varchar(45)',), (b'varchar(45)',)]. This is completely unchanged from how it is returned when i print the cursor content out

Looping through the list gives each tuple as you would expect,however when indexing those tuples, instead of giving a value such as - string = 'hello' - print(string[0]) outputing of course 'h' - a seemingly random number is outputed instead.This means at the moment i cant work out how to validate inputs that need to be validated against the length and datatype of a column

This weird 'b' inclusion only happens on the DATA_TYPE column of the query, so if the query

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'""")
```

is executed the result is

```
[('tblusers', 'user_id', b'int', None, 'NO'), ('tblusers', 'first_name', b'varchar', 45, 'NO'), ('tblusers', 'last_name', b'varchar', 45, 'NO')]
```

**NOTE** this is my first time posting a question on here so do forgive me if i have left out any crucial pieces of infomation needed for someone to help, just let me know and i will try to add that.
Any help is hugely appreciated :)

Comment: `b(value)` defines that variable is in bytes not string format. You can do `b'int'.decode("utf-8")` to only get string **int** for example.

Comment: @TomiL THANK you so much. I just tried that and it works perfectly! Thanks again!